# Stacked solenoids - wire in series or parallel for strongest pull?

Tags: electromagnetic

I have three coils, each 25mm long, which I have bolted together in a stack. I wish to use this to pull in a moving soft-iron core, which will need to be pulled in nearly the full 75mm.
[image]

Each coil takes about 600mA at 12V. What is the best wiring arrangement to get the best / fastest pulling in of the core when current is applied? I'd prefer to wire them in parallel so that I can use a simple 12V supply (e.g. car battery) without any additional electronics (other than a diode across the switch), but if series wiring is better I'll arrange a higher voltage somehow.

Some simple tests suggest little difference, parallel being better, but I may be missing something. I don't know if it is relevant, but the core itself consists of three separate 25mm cores, fixed together with threaded brass rod.

Comment: Based on your diagram, the left coil will stop the movement once the armature hits the base, which will be 25mm of movement. Do you have a lever arrangement to multiply the movement by a factor of 3?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make the movement clear. The diagram shows the armature almost at the end of its travel, it's already been pulled in by ~50mm. Also there's no base to the coils, the armature could pass right through if the controlling piston allowed it.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how amicable the coils are to temporary overvoltage.  If you put them in series, you get a dynamic process affecting the three coils dissimilarly at different times.  Which means that in no way will the voltage be equally distributed across the three coils during that process.  Even if you give the three coils individual flyback diodes, that can land one coil with the full voltage (admittedly mostly when the rod would be shooting out again).

Wiring the coils in parallel would be safer, assuming that your voltage source is fine *sinking* current that the coils may produce.

Comment: Thank you. I may mark your answer correct in due course. It did appear to be more of a jerky movement when in series. I wish it was easier to swap between wiring methods, but the same bolts act as terminals and also hold the coils together, so any change (of a delicate adjustment operation) ends up misaligning the coils, so the armature won't slide smoothly at all.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same. Either use 12 V @ 3 * 600 mA == 1.8 A, or 3 * 12V@600mA == 36 V.

Comment: no, different back EMF in each coil due to motion of armature will be affected differently by series or parallel powering. Maybe Le Chatelier's Principle would allow intuitive ansewer?